# Get all content in all language using query

Tags: nodes, database

I tired to get the content from db using query with some conditions and I need to fetch content in all languages. I have tried two methods, only english language content were fetched, but it doesn't work for all other languages...

Method 1:

```
    $langcd = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
    $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
      ->condition('status', 1)
      ->condition('type', 'page');
      ->condition('langcode', $langcd);
    $nids = $query->execute();
```

Method 2:

```
    $db = \Drupal::database();
    $query = $db->select('node', 'n');
    $query->fields('n');
    $query->condition('type', "page", "=");
    $query->condition('langcode', $langcd);
    $result = $query->execute()->fetchCol();
```

Every time I am getting only the English version of that content, but other language for that particular content was available in db. Please somebody help me to get the content in all other languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following code should work:

```
$langcd = \Drupal::languageManager()->getLanguages();
$langcd = array_keys($langcd);
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
        ->condition('status', 1)
        ->condition('type', 'page');
$query->condition('langcode', $langcd, 'IN');
$nids = $query->execute();
```

Get list of active languages first, then change condition for `langcode` to `IN`.

Comment: Thanks for replying Vishal, I had tried this too but still the problem remains.... and I have found an alternative way for this problem. After loading the node, getting the translation for that node

$node = Node::load(805);
$translation = $node->getTranslation($langcode_yml);

Comment: Yes, this is the correct way to query entities. Probably `IN` is the default operator when the second argument is an array, but that is just a detail.